# Date and Time Field in Django Form

Tags: python, django

I have two field in my django form as well as model, One is date other is time . I want to submit date and time in database. But I haven't succeeded in it yet. Please suggest some code that can make it possible.

form.py

```
class dated1(forms.ModelForm):
    cur_date=forms.DateField()
    cur_time=forms.TimeField(datetime.time)
    class Meta:
        model=dated
```

model.py

```
class dated(models.Model):
    cur_date = models.DateField()
    cur_time = models.TimeField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.cur_date
```

view.py

```
def datetime1(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = dated1(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            f=dated(
                cur_date=request.POST('cur_date'),
                cur_time=request.POST('cur_time'),
            )
            f.save()
            return HttpResponse("Success")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Failure")
    else:
        form = dated1()
        return render(request, 'formdata/dt.html',{'form': form})
```

Comment: well, what happens when it does not work? What is the data you are submitting? etc etc

Comment: 18-10-2014 in date field , 17:49 in time field , I want to submit it in mysql database. If I submit it as 2014-10-18 and 17:49:00, then it is submitted successfully but not in any other format. I want it should submit in any format user provide.

Comment: then you'll have to write code to do that conversion. Or submit it from the client side in a known format which should be possible as you control that side of things!

Comment: thanx for help brother :) 
problem is resolved. the way I resolved has been answered in second answer. please take a look at code. it is strange but it can have an answer too.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
f=dated(
          cur_date=request.POST('cur_date'),
          cur_time=request.POST('cur_time'),
        )
 f.save()
```

try this

```
f = form.save(commit=False)
f.save()
```

Comment: thanx for help brother :) 
problem is resolved. the way I resolved has been answered in second answer. please take a look at code. it is strange but it can have an answer too.

Answer (score 0):

in the template, I made some changes :

```
{% extends 'formdata/template1.html' %}
{% block js %}
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {
            $( "#id_cur_date" ).datepicker({dateFormat: $.datepicker.ATOM});
        });

        $(function()
        {
            $('#id_cur_time').timepicker({timeFormat: 'H:i:s'});
        });


</script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <form id="dtform" method="post" action="#">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h3>Date:</h3>
        {{ form.cur_date }}
        <h3>Time:</h3>
        {{ form.cur_time }}&nbsp;<br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

then I made some changes in views.py

```
def datetime1(request):
if request.method =='POST':
    form = dated1(request.POST)
    f=dated(
        cur_date=request.POST['cur_date'],
        cur_time=request.POST['cur_time']
    )
    f.save(force_insert=True)
    return HttpResponse("Success")
else:
    form = dated1()
    return render(request, 'formdata/dt.html',{'form': form})
```

now when I remove "if form.is_valid()" in the views, it has been submitted successfully in standard format I wanted. Also I add a date picker and time picker through jQuery.
with this answer my question is; why the statement "if form.is_valid()" was not working in above case. @abhi @Paul Collingwood